# Solving integral using feynman trick

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, error-function

For $x,t > 0 \ $  I want to prove
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x n)}{x \ n} e^{-t n^2} dn = \text{erf} \left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right) $$
using the feynman trick. My problem is I don't know which function to use it on.
For example if I want to find $f(u)$ such that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial u} f(u) = \frac{e^{- u t n^2}}{n}
$$
I would have to take a principal value, which can't be helpful. Does anyone have a tip?

Comment: Mabye I should try to solve $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ first? Also I tried to substitute $$\eta := n \ 2 \sqrt{t}$$ in order to get $$ x \ n = \frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}} \ \eta$$ but I'm also not sure how to continue from this.

Comment: For the less sophisticated of us, what is the ‘Feynman trick’?

Comment: It is a very powerful trick for calculating integrals by finding a function that has the derivative of the integrand. It is good described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a function $g$ by
$$g(n,x,t)=\frac{\sin(x n)}{xn} e^{-t n^2}$$
for $n,x,t > 0$.
Now,
$$\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(n,x,t)=-n\frac{\sin(x n)}{x} e^{-t n^2}$$
Therefore
$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{\partial g}{\partial t}(n,x,t) dn = -\frac1{2x}\int_0^\infty  \sin(nx)e^{-tn^2} 2ndn \\=-\frac1{2x}\int_0^\infty  \sin(\sqrt{n}x)e^{-tn} dn$$
By the Laplace transform of $\sin(\sqrt{n}x)$, we have
$$\frac1{x}\mathcal{L}\{\sin(\sqrt{n}x)\}(t)=\frac1{x}\int_0^\infty  \sin(\sqrt{n}x)e^{-tn} dn=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-x^2/4t}}{2t^{\frac32}}$$
Now since
$$-\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x n)}{xn} e^{-t n^2} dn =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}e^{-x^2/4t}}{4t^{\frac32}} $$
you can get the result finally beacuse
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial t}\text{erf} \left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)=-\frac{x e^{-x^2/4t}}{2\sqrt{\pi}t^{\frac32}}$$
and
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\text{erf} \left(\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}\right)=\text{erf}(0)=0\text{ for all }x>0$$

Comment: seriously how do you see this?

Comment: @justabit Experience can make you see everything in a problem. Keep practicing.

Comment: nice one this is

Comment: @SahanManodya is it possible that there are some small mistakes in it?
In line 2 when I don't get the factor 2:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\sin(xn)}{xn}e^{-t n^2} \\
= \frac{\sin(xn)}{xn} e^{-t n^2} (-n^2) \\
= \frac{\sin(xn)}{x} e^{-t n^2} (-n)
$$
Also the derivation of $$\text{erf} (\frac{x}{2 \sqrt{t}}) = \frac{x}{\pi} T$$ where T is what you wrote.
Still the calculation works fine, I just have to adapt the solution a bit, or am I missing something?

Comment: @justabit Yes, you are correct. Thank you for pointing out. I'll correct it